# Android SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19

Tags: android, exception, sqlite

I have this database structure:

```
protected static final String Buildings =
        "CREATE TABLE " 
                + Building.BUILDING_TAG + " ( " 
                + Building.ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY, "
                + Building.NOME + " TEXT,"
                + Building.POSIZIONE + " TEXT, " 
                + Building.DESCRIZIONE + " TEXT, "
                + Building.DATA_C + " LONG, "
                + Building.DATA_U + " LONG, "
                + Building.LINK + " TEXT, "
                + Building.NUMERO_DI_PIANI + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + Building.VERSIONE + " INTEGER, "
                + Building.FOTO + " TEXT, "
                + Building.GEOMETRIA + " TEXT "
                +");";
```

And I'm trying to insert this data:

```
id=6 
descrizione=nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita 
data_creazione=1353904373000 
geometria=[[46074778,13234062],[46074778,13235521],[46073945,13235521],[46073885,13233976],[46074778,13234062],] 
versione=1 
link=http://www.caso.com/ 
nome=erferf 
foto= 
posizione=[46074332,13234748] 
data_update=1355731095000
```

Every time I delete the database from the simulator, and, in the code, I try to delete an eventual building with the same id.

Here is the error:

```
E/Database(16622): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
E/Database(16622):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
E/Database(16622):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
E/Database(16622):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
E/Database(16622):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: you don't have thousands of constraints, that should be quick to figure out which one is not respected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking left when the error was at right.

I forgot to save also the field **numero_di_piani**

So stupid!